# Soundcloud Stratus Player won't work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Why won't my code below work and bring up the Soundcloud Stratus player? :( I don't know Javascript much obviously. They say that's all you have to do and it'll come up, but it won't. I've tried a lot of things! :(

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <title>Blazing Audio | Buy Beats & Instrumentals For $1</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://stratus.sc/stratus.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
 <!-- SCRIPTS -->
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('body').stratus({
      auto_play: true,
      download: false,
      links: 'https://soundcloud.com/blazingaudio/sets/rap-instrumentals',
      random: true
    animate: slide,
    buying: true,
    position: fixed,
    user: false,
    stats: false,
    align: bottom,
    });
  });
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you are using a plugin you will have to include an external js within your page

Comment: Oops idk why It's not on there, I have put that and it still wont work. Idk why mine sucks

Comment: can you update your question with your new code?

Comment: okay, I just updated it.

Comment: See my answer.It should solve your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add external js in the following order:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://stratus.sc/stratus.js"></script>
```

---

I updated your code and it is now working:

### [See this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zword/D7826/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('body').stratus({
    auto_play: true,
    download: false,
    links: 'https://soundcloud.com/blazingaudio/sets/rap-instrumentals',
    random: true,
    buying: true,
    user: false,
    stats: false,
});
});
```

### Entire code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title> - jsFiddle demo by Zword</title>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js'></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/result-light.css">
  <script type='text/javascript' src="http://stratus.sc/stratus.js"></script>

<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
$(document).ready(function(){
$('body').stratus({
  auto_play: true,
  download: false,
  links: 'https://soundcloud.com/blazingaudio/sets/rap-instrumentals',
  random: true,
  buying: true,
  user: false,
 stats: false,
});
});
});//]]>  

</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: nope :( but thanks for that tip for future references.

Comment: Can you post the entire thing? It still wont appear to me, what could I be doing wrong, (Im sorry)